# Bypass approval process of SharePoint page publishing process?

Tags: publishing-site, content-approval

I am using SharePoint 2007 + Windows Server 2008 with SharePoint 2007's publishing portal template.

When publish a page, I have to go through check-in/request for approval/approve process. Any solutions to skip request for approval and approval process (i.e. when we check-in an item, it will be published directly without approval)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the Workflow and Approval Process from the pages Library.

To do so Site Actions - > View All Site Content - > Open Pages Lib and In the Pages Library select Settings -> Document Library Settings -> Versioning settings

Select the Following Say **no** to **Require content approval for submitted items?**
Select **No Versioning**

And In Workflow settings you can remove the Workflow.

Comment: Is turning off "Require content approval for submitted items" enough to disable the approval process only?

Comment: @Alex : I have changed the Answer, we need to remove the WF else there will be an additional step to approve the items through the workflow.

Comment: Cool Kusek! Question answered!

Comment: @Kusek: Nice one. Good to see you here by the way - welcome! :)